# Why is this "Delete Method of Range class failed" error popping up?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to figure out why this "Delete Method of Range Class" error is popping up.  It does not always occur when this macro runs, which makes it all the more perplexing.

Can anybody explain this?

```
Sub ResetSheet()
If WindowsOS Then

    '*******************************************************************************************************'
'Resets the Data sheet.  Called by the resetSheetButton procedure (located in module: m7_Macros1_5).    '
'Also called by the OkCommandButton_Click procedure in the OnOpenUserForm form.                         '
    '*******************************************************************************************************'

Application.EnableEvents = False

Sheet4.Visible = True
Sheet4.Activate
Sheet4.Select
Sheet4.Rows("2:101").Select
Selection.Copy

'TC Edit
Sheet1.Activate
Sheet1.Range("A2").PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll)
'Sheet1.Paste
Sheets("Data").Select
Sheet1.Rows("102:10000").EntireRow.Delete
Sheet4.Visible = False

'TC Edit 2.0 - Adding code to reset the exception checkboxes
If WindowsOS Then
    Call resetCheckBoxes
End If

Application.EnableEvents = True
```

[This is the macro code that causes the error (sometimes)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0U16s.png)

[This is the error pop-up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQV4P.png)

Comment: Do those rows exists?

Comment: there is an end if, I didn't show the entire code, as it is unnecessary.  The error is occurring at the line "Sheet1.Rows("102:10000").EntireRow.Delete"

Comment: A problem which cannot be replicated and seems to occur at random is always hard to solve. Did you un-comment everything but this line to check if that runs without problems? Is the sheet unprotected when you are trying to delete the rows? Are there shapes / buttons / form controls or ActiveX controls on the sheet? In the latter of which deleting rows with such objects (move and size with cells) got me into problems in the past.

Comment: Why are you selecting `data` then deleting rows on `sheet1`? Are they the same?

Comment: Yes, the sheet is protected and there are Active X controls on the sheet. I am really starting to hate how finicky Excel VBA can be.

Comment: The selecting and then deleting was put in there to try and avoid this error.

Comment: It is not a failure to unprotect the sheet.  The sheets are protected with "UserInterfaceOnly:=True"  Shouldn't that not apply to macros running?

Comment: Please post more code. There's more going on.

Comment: Can you get away with using .ClearContents instead of .Delete?

Answer (score 2):

try with below simplified code

```
Sub ResetSheet()
    'If WindowsOS Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    With Worksheets("Sheet4")
        .Visible = True
        .Rows("2:101").Copy Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2")
    End With
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        .Rows("102:101").EntireRow.Delete
    End With
    Worksheets("Sheet4").Visible = False
    If windowsOS Then
        Call resetCheckBoxes
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```